# check input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to build a function to show and hiden a form in HTML by a line of text. How can I add attribute 'require' when it show? Am I wrong anywhere? My checkForm() function doesn't work.

This is HTML code

```
 <h2 onClick="Show()" id="mytext"> Show Register Form </h2>

 <form id="myform">

     your name <input type="text" id="t1" /><br> email <input type="text" id="t2"><br>

     <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="checkForm()">

 </form>
```

This is my class open and close in css file

```
.close {
    display: none;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}
```

This is Javascript code

```
 function Show() {
   var x = document.getElementById('myform');
   if (x.className == "close") {
       x.className = "open";
       document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = "Hide Register Form";
   } else {
       x.className = "close";
       document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = "Show Register Form";
   }
  }

 function checkForm() {

      var x = document.getElementById('myform');

      if (x.className == "open") {

          document.getElementById('t1').setAttribute('required', true);

          document.getElementById('t2').setAttribute('required', true);

     } else {

          document.getElementById('t1').removeAttribute('required');

          document.getElementById('t2').removeAttribute('required');

     }

 }
```

Comment: where you have added class `open` to the form?

Comment: I create it in css file

Comment: add `Show` function here

Comment: To be honest, for me it's a bit unclear what you're asking and actually trying to achieve with this piece of code? Could you clarify a little, so it'd be easier to provide a correct answer.

Comment: We need to see the `Show()` function. But also your form doesn't seem to have the "close" class to begin with, so it will never be invisible. Did you miss some other code out too?

Comment: @LeThiTieuMaiK14HL you need a function `Show` which will trigger on click of `h2`

Comment: `.removeAttribute()` takes only one parameter. (Just a side note, won't fix the problem.)

Comment: Since you are showing and hiding the whole form, why not just put the `required` attribute on the textboxes, in the HTML, by default? You don't need any JavaScript, just add it to the markup. The form cannot be submitted by the user if the whole form is not visible. I can't see any point to this idea, to be honest. If you were just showing/hiding some individual fields it would make sense, but not if you're hiding the entire form.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Okee

Comment: @ADyson I want to use javascript to set it

Comment: @LeThiTieuMaiK14HL Why? It doesn't benefit you. That was my point. There's no need to make it complicated by using JavaScript. `your name <input type="text" id="t1" required /><br> email <input type="text" id="t2" required ><br>` will achieve the same result with a lot less effort.

Comment: @ADyson my HTML cannot be changed

Comment: Even if you can't change the HTML, there's no point in toggling the attribute every time you show or hide the form. Just add the attribute once when the page loads and you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @LeThiTieuMaiK14HL why not? That's a bit strange. It's only an attribute anyway, it won't break anything else. If someone else can amend the HTML, get them to amend it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add in your function show() a code that adds the attribute required to the input.

using javascript:

```
function show() {
    myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    if (!myForm.classList.contains("show")) {
        myForm.classList.add("show");
        document.getElementById('t1').setAttribute('required', true);
        document.getElementById('t2').setAttribute('required', true);
    }else {
        myForm.classList.remove("show");
        document.getElementById('t1').removeAttribute('required');
        document.getElementById('t2').removeAttribute('required');
    }
}
```

using jQuery

```
function show() {
    $('#myForm').toggleClass('show');
    if ($('#myForm').is(':visible')) {
        $('#myForm').find('input').attr('required','required');
    }else {
        $('#myForm').find('input').removeAttr('required');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping all your logic in one function? Something like this. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3frm956o/2/).

**HTML**

```html
<h2 onclick="toggleShow()" id="heading">Show</h2>

<form id="form" class="close">
   Name: <input type="text" id="t1" /> <br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" id="t2" /> <br>

   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkForm()">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.close { display: none; }
.open { display: block; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleShow() {
   const x = document.getElementById('form').className == "open";

   if (x) {
      document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = "Show";

      document.getElementById('t1').required = false;
      document.getElementById('t2').required = false;

      document.getElementById('form').className = "close";
   } else {
      document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = "Hide";

      document.getElementById('t1').required = true;
      document.getElementById('t2').required = true;

      document.getElementById('form').className = "open";
   }
}

function checkForm() { /* Your validation logic here... */ }
```